# Effcient triple index matrix calcs in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting

I am trying to run triple matrix indexing in NumPy and although my code seems to be doing what I want it to, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way as the run time is too long with large matrices.

I have two numpy matrices containing travel times between origin-destination pairs, the first one being for trip leg 1 (from i to k), the second for trip leg 2 (from k to j). I want to create two new matrices:
- the first matrix containing the minimum travel time for each i-j pair (i.e. the lowest time for i to k + k to j)
- the second matrix showing the index of the optimal k intermediate stop that returned this minimum travel time.

My code is as follows:

```
nb_zones = 100
leg1 = np.random.rand(nb_zones,nb_zones)
leg2 = np.random.rand(nb_zones,nb_zones)

# initialise result matrices
total = np.zeros((nb_zones,nb_zones))
index = np.zeros((nb_zones,nb_zones))

# triple index calcs
for a in range(nb_zones):
    for b in range(nb_zones):
        # max
        total[a,b] = np.min(leg1[a] + leg2[:,b])
        # index
        index[a,b] = np.argmin(leg1[a] + leg2[:,b])
```

With number of zones of 800, this leads to up to 30 seconds of run time, is there a more clever way to do this, without the double loop through all matrix cells?

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy broadcast and specifying an axis on `np.min` and `np.argmin` you can avoid one for-loop:

```
for b in range(nb_zones):
    # max
    total[:,b] = np.min(leg1 + leg2[:,b], axis=1)
    # index
    index[:,b] = np.argmin(leg1 + leg2[:,b], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

No loops:

```
duallegs = leg1[:,:,np.newaxis] + leg2[np.newaxis, :]
index = np.argmin(duallegs, axis=1)

rowidx, colidx = np.mgrid[0:nb_zones, 0:nb_zones]
total = duallegs[(rowidx, index, colidx)]
```

Timing:

```
import numpy as np

nb_zones = 800
leg1 = np.random.rand(nb_zones,nb_zones)
leg2 = np.random.rand(nb_zones,nb_zones)

def f1():
    # initialise result matrices
    total = np.zeros((nb_zones,nb_zones))
    index = np.zeros((nb_zones,nb_zones))

    # triple index calcs
    for a in range(nb_zones):
        for b in range(nb_zones):
            # max
            total[a,b] = np.min(leg1[a] + leg2[:,b])
            # index
            index[a,b] = np.argmin(leg1[a] + leg2[:,b])

    return total, index

def f2():
    duallegs = leg1[:,:,np.newaxis] + leg2[np.newaxis, :]
    index = np.argmin(duallegs, axis=1)

    rowidx, colidx = np.mgrid[0:nb_zones, 0:nb_zones]
    total = duallegs[(rowidx, index, colidx)]

    return total, index

%timeit f1()
%timeit f2()

8 s ± 819 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
4.85 s ± 360 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Both this and the other suggestion working great, thanks. I was surprised that the difference in runtime between my script and these seems to decrease as the matrix size (number of zones) increases, whereas I would have expected the other way around.